# Access violation in coreide140.bpl, C++ Builder 2010 on Windows Server 2016

Tags: c++, c++builder, windows-server-2016, c++builder-2010

I'm trying to install C++ Builder 2010 on a Windows Server 2016 64-bit system and tried to open C++ Builder application. I then ran into the issue with a .ttr file and have used the recommended batch file to resolve that. However, now when opening Builder, I get the following two messages:

1:

> Error: A call to an OS function failed

2:

> Access violation at address 20981C6D in module 'coreide140.bpl'. Read of address 00000000.

Comment: Why are you using tools that are a decade out of date?

Comment: Just trying to save on buying new licensed version. Eventually will ask the organisation to buy if nothing works out. So trying to make it work out as far as I can.

Comment: You can use the latest version of Visual Studio free of charge as long as you don't need the Pro or enterprise version. The VC build tools are free.

Comment: Yes, But some part of the code are legacy code and are written in Borland C++. Those were never migrated to work on VS. Will have to find a way to port that now if C++ Builder does't work properly or if they doesn't want to buy new license of C++ Builder

Comment: Sounds like you should just try to write *standard* compliant C++. Then *any* compiler should work.

Comment: Well why aren't you trying to do it in older OS and check what happens.

Comment: Yes @JesperJuhl . But as I said this is a legacy code written years ago.

Comment: @JamesZ In the older version i.e WS 2008 it works just fine. The thing is I am trying to migrate the application from WS2008 to WS2016. So compiling the code on WS2016

Comment: @JesperJuhl "*You can use the latest version of Visual Studio free of charge as long as you don't need the Pro or enterprise version*" - Embarcadero also provides a free Community edition of C++Builder.